# Xcode 8.3 Archive error: Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I started getting this error only after upgrading from Xcode 8.2 to Xcode 8.3, and *only when making an archive build* (debug builds work fine).

When I do the archive via Xcode, the only message I get is "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

I build with the command line `xcodebuild -scheme MyProduct`

When I built this way, I found a number of issues (again, only when doing Archive):

- I had to add `import UIKit` to practically every swift file.
- all the pods had issues
- remove everything from app-Bridging-Header.h
- add a few things back into app-Bridging-Header.h

My current issue is with the AWS pod, using version 2.5.3

So my app-Bridging-Header.h has `#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>`

Here is the error from the command line build:

```
error: 'AWSS3/AWSS3.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
        ^
```

The error log continues after that.  I also tried the crazy suggestion of switch in the import to "AWSS3/AWSS3.h"...that didn't work either.

What is going on?

*More INFO*

This really appears to be an issue with one of my pods.  I built a new solution, imported a subset of my pods and everything built.  Then when I updated with the full list of pods it broke.

Comment: Did you try to use 8.3.1? Apple deprecated Xcode 8.1 archives [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html). Maybe something wrong with Xcode

Comment: Are you using the xcworkspace generated by cocoapods or the xcodeproject?

Comment: @AitorPagán, yes I am using the workspace, not the xcodeproject.

Comment: @svvoff, thank you. I will look into that.

Comment: @svvoff, just update to XCode 8.3.1.  No change in the build.  Still getting the dreaded "Linker command failed with exit code 1"

Comment: Have you contacted the developers of AWS ?

Comment: @Koen, on further investigation, I'm not sure it is really an AWS issue at all.  Instead it looks like a cocoapods issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At long last I was able to figure out this was a pod issue...just had to figure out which one it was.

I created a brand new project and started adding my pods in one by one (actually, 3 by 3...one by one would have taken too long).

Conclusion: localytics 4.3.1 has a bug in it somewhere.  I downgraded to 4.3.0 and the problem went away.

Comment: hello @chris i am stuck in pod i found error Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group . clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 12):

For me it is coming due to `Bitcode` enable in my project and i have used a custom framework with disabled bitcode.

Two things you can do :

1. Either disable `bitcode` in your project

   **OR**
2. Build framework with `bitcode` enable

**NOTE**: If you click on error and it doesn't show anything then right click on error and select **Reveal in Log**. You will get error for this issue

Comment: Thank you so much for your NOTE

Answer (score 0):

I got a problem like this. My suggestion is that you should remove the version of 8.3 and download any old version from this link: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ 
I hope that it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Turns out it was an issue with one of my pods.  You can see my answer below for details.