# XCode 8.3 Archive failed, no actual error message

Tags: ios, xcode

- Xcode 8.3.3
- Swift 3
- Using Cocoa Pods, listed below

I am getting the error:

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Yet there is no specific error message. When I click on the "Linker command failed..." message in the left panel of Xcode I am not taken anywhere and there is no further details of the error message.

My current `Enable Bitcode` setting is "No" though I have tried setting it to "Yes" as well. The only reason I tried that is [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350057/xcode-8-3-archive-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1)

My Cocoa Pods could be suspect from what I have read online, here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '9.0'

abstract_target 'commonPods' do
    # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for app
    pod 'MetaWear'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'Firebase', '4.0.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth', '4.0.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Database', '4.0.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage', '4.0.0'
    pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.2'
    pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.2'
    pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.2'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.22.1'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.22.1'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.22.1'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'

    target 'app' do

    end

    target 'app Lite' do

    end
end
```

The reason for my specific versions of the Facebook Cocoa Pods in my Podfile is because there is a Swift 3 issue with latest Facebook SDKs, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44689990/1258525).

I have Cleaned and restarted XCode. My Xcode project/workspace builds and runs fine on devices and simulators.

Is there in Error Log files for Xcode that I could look for further details of an error message?

Any suspect Cocoa Pods?

Comment: Look at the Report Navigator pane for full details of the problem.

Comment: I know it sounds silly for mentioning such a trivial note, but have you tried to clean and rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved the lack of error message because there is an error message and it is just on an area of Xcode I am unfamiliar with. I found the area of Xcode that displays Archive errors and found error message details:
[image]

This of course gave me the direction I needed, I do not know the when, where, who and why "Pod_app" was created as a Link, something with some version of Cocoa Pods, I have been working on this project over a year and this is my first Archive. app is the name of my app.

Removing this "Pod_app" Framework from the picture below (click the "-" with it highlighted) allowed my Archive to be created without error. Oh bittersweet technology. The picture below shows the after of removing "Pod_app". I am skeptical that the "Pods_commonPods__app.framework" link is needed either but I am not messing with it right now, I can Archive and that is all that matters for me to start my Friday night :).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add your pod under your **app target** as below .

```
 abstract_target 'commonPods' do
        # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks



   target 'app' do
        use_frameworks!

         # Pods for app
        pod 'MetaWear'
        pod 'MBProgressHUD'
        pod 'RealmSwift'
        pod 'Firebase', '4.0.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Auth', '4.0.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Database', '4.0.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Storage', '4.0.0'
        pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.2'
        pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.2'
        pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.2'
        pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.22.1'
        pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.22.1'
        pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.22.1'
        pod 'GoogleSignIn'
        end

        target 'app lite' do

        end
    end
```

**Run following command in terminal**

```
pod install --repo-update
```